# How does the JWST sunshade cover release work?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, mechanisms

In animations of the James Webb Space Telescope unfolding, you see material rolling itself up to uncover the folded-up sunshade. How is that rolling-up process driven? The animations don't show any obvious mechanism. It looks almost as if the material naturally rolls up like stiff wrapping paper, but that seems a bit uncontrolled. Is there a good lay-oriented explanation?!  [NASA video of sunshade cover release](https://jwst.nasa.gov/content/webbLaunch/assets/video/deploymentSteps/1k/WEBB_allCovers_1280_30fps_h264.mp4)

Comment: Nice question, I would like to see a great a detailed answer for this.